# Configuring ssh not to prompt for password

Tags: ssh, git

I have git successfully installed on one of our Red Hat Linux 5 WS servers, and am using it on our Intranet, not outside our firewall.

Currently, I am prompted for a password when I connect, so what steps do I need to take to make sure the server has the correct keys to avoid prompting for a password? I believe this is an issue of making sure the public keys are present. I'm just not sure how to set that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a keypair, and then copy the public key to the server:

Example:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa user@remotehost
```

Comment: ssh-copy-id on RHEL 5?

Comment: @Peter Do you have a question?

Comment: Still being prompted for password after logging out and back in.

Answer (score 3):

OK, it's easy.
A is the client, B is the target machine. 
You login on A with your credentials.
You generate the ssh key (if you do have it, ignore that step):

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

Defaults are OK.
You know have a file ~/.ssh/id_dsa and a ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
Login on B and execute the commands:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

Go on A again and scp the key file:

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub <username_b>@B:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

where  is the username of B.
Go on B and execute the command:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now, you should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

Check the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file that the 
option

> PubkeyAuthentication yes
>   is set.

Also, I forgot to answer if you try with the root account. In that case, you need to setup the option **PermitRootLogin** 
as

> PermitRootLogin without-password